# Adding transition Image

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I am trying to make a d3 visual through block builder.

I want the picture of tourdefrance to appear first in the whole container and then fade away and then the bars to appear.

I know I have made it a little complicated by copying from various sources.

Would be great if someone could help out and also explain the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: gold;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>

// Mike Bostock "margin conventions"
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: -500, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 -  margin.top - margin.bottom;

// D3 scales = just math
// x is a function that transforms from "domain" (data) into "range" (usual pixels)
// domain gets set after the data loads
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

// D3 Axis - renders a d3 scale in SVG
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "%");

// create an SVG element (appended to body)
// set size
// add a "g" element (think "group")
// annoying d3 gotcha - the 'svg' variable here is a 'g' element
// the final line sets the transform on <g>, not on <svg>

    body = d3.select("body"); 


    show_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Tour_de_France_logo.svg")


function show_image(source) { 
var img = body.append("img").attr("src", source).style("opacity", 0)
;   img.transition().duration(5000).ease(d3.easeLinear).style("opacity", 1)
} 



    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text") // just for the title (ticks are automatic)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)") // rotate the text!
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");






// d3.tsv is a wrapper around XMLHTTPRequest, returns array of arrays (?) for a TSV file
// type function transforms strings to numbers, dates, etc.
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavjaitly/1418c9beb1c71f6acffdaf21669e1956/raw/45af8ebcc87d6641eee8b4a60b7bafb8326607a0/data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  replay(data);
});

function type(d) {
  // + coerces to a Number from a String (or anything)
  d.Frequency = +d.Frequency;
  return d;
}

function replay(data) {
  var slices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    slices.push(data.slice(0, i+1));
  }
  slices.forEach(function(slice, index){
    setTimeout(function(){
      draw(slice);
    }, index * 300);
  });
}

function draw(data) {
  // measure the domain (for x, unique letters) (for y [0,maxFrequency])
  // now the scales are finished and usable
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Frequency; })]);

  // another g element, this time to move the origin to the bottom of the svg element
  // someSelection.call(thing) is roughly equivalent to thing(someSelection[i])
  //   for everything in the selection\
  // the end result is g populated with text and lines!
  svg.select(".x.axis").transition().duration(300).call(xAxis);

  // same for yAxis but with more transform and a title
  svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(300).call(yAxis)

  // THIS IS THE ACTUAL WORK!
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data, function(d) { return d.Letter; }) // (data) is an array/iterable thing, second argument is an ID generator function

  bars.exit()
    .transition()
      .duration(300)
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0))
    .style('fill-opacity', 0.00001024)
    .remove();

  // data that needs DOM = enter() (a set/selection, not an event!)
  bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0));

  // the "UPDATE" set:
  bars.transition().duration(300).attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Letter); }) // (d) is one item from the data array, x is the scale object from above
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Frequency); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Frequency); }); // flip the height, because y's domain is bottom up, but SVG renders top down

}
```

Comment: To start with: You're using `d3.csv` while the data provided at the gist isn't comma separated. Can you please re-check and change it to correct CSV format? Also: in the line where you try to fetch the file using `d3.csv`, there's a syntax issue if you could notice and fix (hint: the closing ')' ). Once you get these couple of things done, do edit the post and we'll get the bar chart working.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Shashank

Comment: Sure no problem.

Comment: @Shashank. I am trying to add the code to transition image but its not working.var body = d3.select("body");

show_image("http://www.defenders.org/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/tiger-dirk-freder-isp.jpg")

function show_image(source) {
  var img = body.append("img").attr("src", source).style("opacity", 0)
  img.transition().duration(5000).ease(d3.easeLinear).style("opacity", 1)
} Could help please. Sorry for the request again

Comment: I still don't see the changes I mentioned in my previous comment. Also: I see no relation between the bar chart you're trying to create in the original question and the image you're trying to transition here in your comment. I'd suggest you to create a question with your exact requirements along with the code you've tried (and understood) to achieve those. And btw the link doesn't work.

Comment: @Shashank Apologies for so much confusion. I have edited my code and also my question.